# Odp.net fails with ORA-000942 (table or view does not exist)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, odp.net

Attempting to execute package stored procedure using ODP.NET

The call fails with message "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist\nORA-06512: at \"SAAP.PKGPRICEWORX\", line 25\nORA-06512:....

However the procedure works fine when run though the server server explorer !.

I am using ODP.net4 assemblies on VS2010;

Any help to resolve this appreciated.

Here is the package:

```
    clear;
/
create or replace
PACKAGE pkgPriceWorx
AS
  defaultQANP NUMBER:=99999999;
 procedure dbg(s varchar2,INDENT NUMBER DEFAULT 0,APPEND NUMBER DEFAULT 0);
FUNCTION frSls031CunoCpgsStdt(    comno VARCHAR2,cuno  VARCHAR2,cpgs  VARCHAR2,stdt DATE,found OUT NUMBER)RETURN baan.ttdsls031010%rowtype ;
FUNCTION frSLS034(  comno VARCHAR2,    cuno  VARCHAR2,    cpgs  VARCHAR2,    found OUT NUMBER)  RETURN baan.ttdsls034010%rowtype;
PROCEDURE prUpdateOrInsertDiscount(    COMNO VARCHAR2 ,    CPLS  VARCHAR2,    CUNO  VARCHAR2 ,    CPGS  VARCHAR2,    stdt DATE ,    DISC IN OUT NUMBER,    O OUT VARCHAR2);
PROCEDURE prUpdateSLS031(R2U baan.ttdsls031010%rowtype,Comno varchar2, RowsUpdated out number); 
PROCEDURE prUpdateOrInsertSLS034(    comno VARCHAR2,    cuno  VARCHAR2,    cpgs  VARCHAR2,    rowCount OUT NUMBER) ;
FUNCTION fnDefaultQANP  RETURN NUMBER ;
procedure testNumPrecision(precie number); 
END ;
/
show error;
/
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY pkgPriceWorx IS
spc varchar2(1):=' ';
jed varchar2(10):='1,J';-- Julian Expiry format
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 procedure dbg(s varchar2,INDENT NUMBER DEFAULT 0,APPEND NUMBER DEFAULT 0) as
 BEGIN
      if append =0 then  
          BEGIN
              DBMS_output.Put_line(s);
          END;
      else
          BEGIN
                dbms_output.Put(s);
          end;
     End if;
END;     
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure prInsertSLS031(comno varchar2,cuno varchar2,cpgs varchar2,stdt Date,disc number, rowCount out number) as
  sQ varchar2(3000);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('@prInsertSLS031');
  sQ:= ' Insert into baan.ttdsls031' ||comno|| '(t$cuno,t$cpgs,t$dile,t$qanp               ,t$stdt    ,t$tdat                                     ,t$disc ,t$damt,t$cdis,t$gnpr,t$refcntd,t$refcntu)' || '  values(                                                     :cuno,:cpgs  ,1         ,:qanp                   ,:stdt      ,to_date('||'''1' || ''' ,'||'''J '''||')   ,:disc   ,0         ,' || '''  '''||'   ,1          ,0              ,0)';
  dbms_output.put_line(sQ);
  EXECUTE immediate sQ USING cuno,cpgs,defaultqanp,STDT,disc;
  rowCount:=sql%rowcount;
END;
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PROCEDURE prUpdateOrInsertDiscount(COMNO VARCHAR2 ,CPLS VARCHAR2, CUNO VARCHAR2 , CPGS VARCHAR2 , stdt date, DISC in out NUMBER ,O out varchar2) AS
    R31 BAAN.TTDSLS031010%ROWTYPE;
    R34 BAAN.TTDSLS034010%ROWTYPE;
    rowCount number;
    sQ varchar2(3000);
    rc number;
    edt date;
    iRC number;
    uRc number;
  BEGIN
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------
   1). Check  SLS031.DISC(Customer and priceGroup, ?OPEN)
         1.1) If a match found 
                    1.2.1) Compare NewDiscount == current      
                               return : 
                   1.2.2) NewDisc != CURRENT
                              I . Update current to expire
                              II. Insert an entry
         2.1) If No match found
                I . insert new 31 entry 

     IDX1=CUNO,CPGS,DILE
     ?open=tdat=4712-01-01;
    ----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    DBG('@prUpdateOrInsertDiscount');
    R31:=frSLS031CunoCpgsStdt(COMNO,cuno,cpgs,stdt,rowCount ); 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ROW COUNT ON FRSLS031='|| ROWCOUNT);


    IF (rowCount > 0) then -- 1.1  Match found
        BEGIN
             dbg('Match found');  
             if((stdt ) > R31.T$STDT Or (disc != R31.t$disc)) then
                  Begin
                      dbg('Ok : OpenRecord has stdt > (stdt-1)');
                      r31.t$tdat:=stdt-1;
                     prUpdateSLS031(R31,comno,uRc);
                     dbg('Updated rowCount ='||urc);
                      prInsertSLS031(comno,cuno,cpgs,stdt,disc, rowCount);
                      return;
                  End;
             end if;      
             dbg('Both stdt and disc has no change.. nothing was done');   
        END;
    ELSE -- NO NMATCH 
        Begin   
                  dbg( ' No Match inserting new ' );       
                  prInsertSLS031(comno,cuno,cpgs,stdt,disc,rowCount);

        End;

   END IF;

  END prUpdateOrInsertDiscount;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 PROCEDURE prUpdateOrInsertSLS034(comno varchar2,cuno varchar2, cpgs varchar2,rowCount out number) AS
      R                 baan.ttdsls034010%rowtype;
     sQ varchar2(3000);
      rc   number;
      cpls varchar2(3);
      cuni varchar2(3);
BEGIN
      R:=frSls034(comno,cuno,cpgs,rc);
      if (rc > 0 ) then return; end if;
       cpls :=' ';
       cuni :='ea';   
--                sQ:='insert into baan.ttdsls034' ||comno|| '(t$cuno,t$cpgs ,t$dile,t$APYN,T$CPLS,T$STSA,T$STSB,T$STSC,T$KOGR,T$CUNI,T$DMTH,T$REFCNTD,T$REFCNTU)' ;
--                                                                 ' VALUES(:CUNO ,:CPGS ,1       ,2           ,:CPLS   ,2           ,2            ,2           ,1             , :CUNI  ,1             ,0                   ,0)';

                 dbms_output.put_line(sQ);                                       
       execute immediate sQ using cuno,cpgs,cpls,cuni; 
 END prUpdateOrInsertSLS034;
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function fnDefaultQANP return number is n number;
  Begin
    return defaultQANP;
  End;
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function frSls031CunoCpgsStdt(comno varchar2,cuno varchar2,cpgs varchar2,stdt date,found out number) return baan.ttdsls031010%rowtype is
      r baan.ttdsls031010%rowtype;
      sQ varchar2(600);
  BEGIN
    sQ           :='SELECT *  FROM BAAN.TTDSLS031'||COMNO || ' WHERE ' || 
    ' TRIM(T$CUNO)=trim( :CUNO)  AND ' || ' TRIM(T$CPGS)=trim( :CPGS)  AND ' || 
    ' T$QANP      = :qanp AND ' ||
    ' t$tdat =(select MIN(t$tdat) from baan.ttdsls031'||comno||' where trim(t$cuno)=trim(:cuno) ' ||
    ' and trim(t$cpgs)=trim(:cpgs) and t$qanp=:qanp) ';

    execute immediate sQ into r using cuno,cpgs,fndefaultQanp,cuno,cpgs,fndefaultQanp; 
    found:=sql%rowcount;
    RETURN R;
   exception
    when 
        no_data_found then  found:=-1;    
        return null;

  end;

-------------------------------------------------------------
  function frSLS034(comno varchar2,cuno varchar2,cpgs varchar2,found out number) return baan.ttdsls034010%rowtype is
      r baan.ttdsls034010%rowtype;
    sQ varchar2(3000);
  BEGIN
      sQ :='SELECT *  FROM BAAN.TTDSLS034'||COMNO || ' WHERE' || ' TRIM(T$CUNO)= trim(:CUNO)  AND ' || ' TRIM(T$CPGS)=trim( :CPGS)';
      EXECUTE immediate sQ INTO r USING cuno,cpgs;
      FOUND:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
      RETURN R;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
      found:=-1;
      return null;  
END;
----
PROCEDURE prUpdateSLS031(R2U baan.ttdsls031010%rowtype,Comno varchar2,RowsUpdated out number) as
  sQ varchar2(3000);
Begin
    sQ:='update baan.ttdsls031'||comno|| '  set t$tdat=:rtdat where  t$cuno=:cuno and t$cpgs=:cpgs and t$dile=:dile and t$qanp=:qanp and t$stdt = :stdt ';
    dbg( '@prUpdateSLS031');
    dbg('     '||sQ);
    execute immediate SQ using R2U.t$tdat  ,  R2U.t$cuno , R2U.t$cpgs , R2U.t$dile , R2U.t$qanp , R2U.t$stdt;
    RowsUpdated:=Sql%rowCount;
End ;
----
procedure testNumPrecision(precie number)as
Begin
null;
end;
-------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------
END pkgPriceWorx;
/
show error;
/
```

Comment: What is at line 25 of `SAAP.pkgPriceWorx`?  Is the procedure doing dynamic SQL?  Is it an invoker's rights stored procedure?  Are you logged in as the same Oracle user in both cases?  Are you sure that you're passing exactly the same parameters?

Comment: @JustinCave , Yes it is doing Dynamic sql, (and failiure is right at the place where it is executing dynamic sql. Yes, I am logged in with same account in both cases, and I am sure passing exactly the same parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks for bothering you and thanks to  Justin Cave for hinting where could be the error, It was a error in the net code, in which I had lopped a character in the parameter name, so when the dynamic sql was constructing the code, it did not find the parameter specified (which is suffix of the one of the table).